# Foreign key attribute not valid when trying to use in one to many relationship in EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two POCO classes as 
Employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
     Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
    }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

public String EmployeeName { get; set; }

public int DeptId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("DeptId")]
public  ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }

}
```

Department class

```
public class Department
    {      
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
     }
```

I wanted to name the foreign key in Emp-Department one to many relationship other than the default EF naming convention. So I haved used the `ForeignKey` attribute in `Employee`. But I get Exception

> Foreign Key attribute on property Departments on type `Employee` is not
>   valid

Help me figure out the way to name Foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Employee has a Foreign Key Property pointing to Department, then an Employee cannot have multiple Departments.  So change the navigation property to:

```
[ForeignKey("DeptId")]
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```